# Descent and Chow groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motivic-cohomology, motivic-homotopy, chow-groups

One of the features of the $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy theory is the existence of the motivic Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(\mathbb{Z}(n),2n)$ such that for $k$-schemes $X$, we have
$$[X,K(\mathbb{Z}(n),2n)]\cong \text{Ch}^{n}(X)$$
where $[\cdot,\cdot]$ denotes the $\text{Hom}$ in the homotopy categroy of $k$-schemes $H(k)$. Hence I'm wondering for which Grothendieck topologies the Chow groups are sheaves? I'm sure there is plenty of good literature, but I haven't managed to find it. I would be very glad if someone could explain it to me or point me the right way.

Comment: $CH^1$ is not a sheaf for the Zariski topology (if it were, we would have $\operatorname{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^1)=0 $), so probably not for any reasonable Grothendieck topology.

Comment: @abx sorry but could you spell out exactly why it is not a sheaf for the Zariski topology? Physicist here.

Comment: @JamalS The argument abx is refering to is that we have a Zariski covering $\mathbb{A}^1\cup \mathbb{A}^1$ of $\mathbb{P}^1$. If $Pic$ were to satisfy the Zariski sheaf condition, then we would have an injection $$0\rightarrow Pic(\mathbb{P}^1)\rightarrow Pic(\mathbb{A}^1)\times  Pic(\mathbb{A}^1).$$ However, $Pic(\mathbb{P}^1)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $Pic(\mathbb{A}^1)=0$, so this can not be.

Comment: @curious math guy the representability of the chow groups shouldn't give you descent for the set of homotopy classes of maps into it but rather of the entire space of maps. In this case it boils down to the zariski descendability of the motivic complex of weight 2n or, not any particular cohomology of it. Classically this means you have a spectral sequence computing the sections on a union, involving all the cohomologies together.